# Send Ajax request to get json data from json file with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, web-services, local-files

I want to send an AJAX request with pure JS without using a server or idling the security in the Chrome browser.

**This is my code:**

```
if(document.getElementById("showJson")){
    document.getElementById("showJson").addEventListener("click", init);
}

function init(){
    loadJSON(function (response){
        var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
    });
}

function loadJSON(callback) {   
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'my_data.json', true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
          }
    };
    xobj.send(null);  
    console.log(xobj);
 }
```

**and this is the JSON file "students":**

```
[{
    "name" : "Mohamed Kamel",
    "age" : 24,
    "grade" : 100
},{
    "name": "hamada",
    "age" : 20,
    "grade":90
},{
    "name" : "ali",
    "age" : 23,
    "grade" : 80
}]
```

Comment: So what is the problem with your code? What do you mean "without using a server"? Are you opening the web page from the local file system rather than from a web server?

Comment: I want to show the json object using console.log()
but this error appears "MLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/hamada/Desktop/Mohamed%20Kamel/assign3/students.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Comment: You need a server to serve your JSON file.

Comment: I think that this job can be done by editing the header but I don't know how?!! so can you help ?!!

Comment: Cross origin request appears instead the json object I want to do that without server by javascript only

Answer (score 0):

**You can not.**

For security reasons downloading a file must be done only by user permit.

But why you want to do this? There is no difference (in performance) for server to read a file and send content or send the file. In both ways server reads the file.

Comment: I am just curios about it I know that there is a way but I don't know how?!

Comment: Its ok, I am curios like you, But it is not possible.

Comment: If it was a way, There was very easy to find many articles by one search. If js could download files without user permit, it would download bad files to hack the user.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your running into a 'Cross origin' problem.  If the file you are requesting is on another domain the base headers there might be set 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin'.  If the owner of that site wants to be able to share that JSON file with anyone they should change the name from .json to .php and add this to its header.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```